# Cannot bind VBO-Object (glGenBuffers not found)

Tags: python, opengl

I am using **Python 3.5** on Windows 10.
I have already installed **PyOpenGL 3.1** and **PyOpenGL-accelerate 3.1.2** via pip.

When my simple code wants to bind a VBO object

```
# points is just a list of points to draw triangles 
self.vb = vbo.VBO(array(self.points, "f"))

# inside draw/display-callback method
self.vb.bind()
```

I am getting the error

```
OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glGenBuffers, check for bool(glGenBuffers) before calling
```

`bool(glGenBuffers)` returns `False`.

This all happens in the context of

```
def main(self):
    glutInit([])
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB)

    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500)
    glutCreateWindow("Title")

    self.init_triangle_points() # Does simple math for points to render

    glutDisplayFunc(self.display) # Binding happens in here
    self.init_gl()

    glutMainLoop()
```

Can you help?

Comment: Do you have a valid OpenGL context when calling this code?

Comment: @BDL I am not even sure what you mean by that.

Comment: You can only execute OpenGL commands when you have create a valid OpenGL context first and have loaded all extension functions. This is often done by `glutInit`, `glutInitDisplayMode` and `glutCreateWindow`. But it's unclear how your program looks at the moment. You should create a minimal and complete example code that shows the problem.

Comment: @BDL Thanks for clearing up. I just added the context to my question.